# How to use different size chart for different products in Magento

Tags: magento, charts, size

I need to add different size chart for different products to my magento store.

Can anybody explain here, How to do this and also give me a solution to do this.

Thanks in advance
formygalaxy

Comment: The answer was not accepted by the OP even when he agrees that he got the solution

Answer (score 1):

You could do so linking a product attribute (e.g. manufacturer) with static blocks.

See this code:

```
$sizeGuideIdentifier = trim($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'));
$sizeGuideIdentifier = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($sizeGuideIdentifier)) .'-size-guide';

if($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($sizeGuideIdentifier)->toHtml()):

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($sizeGuideIdentifier)->toHtml();

else:

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product-sizeguide')->toHtml();

endif;
```

It will try to echo out a block called e.g. "nike-sizeguide", if this block doesn't exist it will fall back to the default sizeguide.

Comment: Hi erwin, thanks a ton for your answer. It would be greatful if you explain this in detail to me. like, where to install this code and how to integrate this into product page and etc. thanks in advance

Comment: You can put this snippet anywhere on the product view template: /magento/app/design/frontend/[packagename]/[templatename]/catalog/product/view.phtml

After that, create a static block and name the identifier product-sizeguide.

If you want to use different sizeguides for specific brand, create a sizeguide with an identifier nike-sizeguide. Go to your product in the backend and set manufacturer as nike, and it should pick up the nike specific size guide.

Comment: Thanks erwin, i haven't set any 'manufacturer', my category for men is (/men/formal-shirts/regular.html) and women (women/tops/blouse.html). how to change your code according to this.

Comment: can you explain me how to give the link in block to open a popup?, if yes, i will put all the sizes in the one block and give the link to the another block which is already in the product view page

Comment: The best way is setting a attribute for different sizeguides, if you don't use the manufacturer attribute, just change the attributecode to something different. If you want it to open in a popup, I recommend using fancybox http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/.

Comment: Thanks erwin. I have tried but when i configure this into the cms block, the add cart option is not working?

Comment: Erwin, got the error due to the jquery version conflicts in my magento. Now it's working fine. thanks again dude

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. Could you please approve/rate my answer?

Answer (score 1):

yup, this worked perfectly on Magento 1.9CE, although for me Erwin's solution needed to be inserted into "app/design/frontend/.../.../template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml".

Really simple solution and great outcome; we now pop a fancybox sizechart image for each brand (manufacturer) automatically, without coding and our inventory managers don't need to think about it.

Really really great - and much appreciation to Erwin Smit.  I hope the good karma has visited you already ;)

```
    <dd <?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
              </select>
          </div>

        <div class="size-box"><?php 
                $sizeGuideIdentifier = trim($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')); 
                $sizeGuideIdentifier = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($sizeGuideIdentifier)) .'-size-guide';
                if($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($sizeGuideIdentifier)->toHtml()):
                echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($sizeGuideIdentifier)->toHtml();
                else:
                echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product-sizeguide')->toHtml();
            endif;?>
        </div>
    </dd>
```